# How to only subscribe to database updates (without fetching)?

Tags: meteor

I have a large database and I only want to send actual data updates to the client.
I do not want each client to fetch the whole set of data as it is done natively with Meteor's pub/subs.
I tried `ground:db` but it still fetched all data.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can [`observeChanges`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes) on your whole collection and channel the changes (`added`, `changed`, `removed`) to each [publication handler](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish).

A very rough application would look like this :

```js
var pubHandlers = []

Meteor.publish('changes stream', function handlePublication() {
  pubHandlers.push(this)
  this.onStop(() =>
    pubHandlers.splice(pubHandlers.indexOf(this), 1)
  )
  this.ready()
})

myCollection.find().observeChanges({
  added : function docAdded(id, doc) {
    for(let pubHandler of pubHandlers) {
      pubHandler.added('my collection', id, doc)
    }
  },
  changed : function docChanged(id, fields) {
    for(let pubHandler of pubHandlers) {
      pubHandler.changed('my collection', id, fields)
    }
  },
  removed : function docRemoved(id) {
    for(let pubHandler of pubHandlers) {
      pubHandler.removed('my collection', id)
    }
  }
})
```

Note that in that case `docRemoved` will throw if the document didn't exist on the client.
In that case, all updates on your collection will be sent to all subscribed clients. You may want to use some smartly distributed [`Mongo.Cursor`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_cursor) to share the load in a cleaner way.

Comment: Thank you! 
On the client: How is myCollection initially populated? And how to feedback changes on the client?

Comment: As you can see in the example code, `'my collection'` is not initially populated. I am unsure as what "feedback changes on the client" means.

Comment: Lets say you have 1000 Tags in the DB.

Comment: How do I get them into the client database. What if the client deletes a doc? How does this get propagated to the server?

Comment: Your question was only about subscribing to pure changes on a Collection. If you have follow-up questions, you should ask them separately.

Comment: Alright. I started another Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33341638/372459

Answer (score 0):

How about cursor.observeChanges?

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes